# improving automated updating user Attributes by comparing two object

Tags: powershell, object, active-directory

im trying to automate the updating on User Attributes, I have this working so far, but it feels like im doing it the hard/dirty way, any suggestions on how to clean it up a bit/ make it tidier?

an if\else statement for each Attribute doesn't feel right but I'm not sure how else to do it

I'm comparing a User's Current Attributes with .csv that has the correct Attributes then if something dosn't match change that to the value in the .csv

```
$csvFile = 'C:\Path'  # Enter a path to your import CSV file
$validUsernameFormat = '[^a-zA-Z_.]'                # identifies anything that's _not_ a-z or underscore or .
$Mailpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -string “4a1fd5e9f7e26f” -AsPlainText -Force
$MailCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "38da1ca9daf082", $Mailpassword
$mailBody = $NewUserParams | out-string



# read the input csv and loop through
Import-Csv -Path $csvFile | ForEach-Object {
    $firstName = $_.FirstName.Trim()
    $surname = $_.Surname.Trim()
    #$validUsernameFormat = "[^a-zA-Z_.]"                                        # identifies anything that's _not_ a-z or underscore or .
    $vaildusername = "($firstName'.'$surname)" -replace $validUsernameFormat, ''       #removes anything that isn'tin $validUsernameFormat
    $truncateifgreaterthanXchar = '(?<=^.{20}).*'
    $username = $vaildusername -replace $truncateifgreaterthanXchar
    $DefaultPassword = 'Pa$$w0rd'
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $DefaultPassword -AsPlainText -Force



    # test if a user with that name already exists
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        $CurrentAttributes = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Properties *
        [psobject]$CorrectAttributes
        $CorrectAttributes = @{
            SamAccountName        = $username; `
                Name              = "$firstname $surname"; `
                DisplayName       = "$firstname $surname"; `
                UserPrincipalName = "$username@domain.com"; `
                GivenName         = $firstname; `
                Surname           = $surname
            Path                  = "CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"; #change to switch based of Users Branch
            City                  = $_.City; `
                Country           = $_.Country; #NOTE: This Feild must be the 2 digit Country Code, NOT the String Name of athe Country.
            department            = $_.OrgDepartmentName; `
                Employeeid        = $_.EmployeeId; `
                mobile            = $_.Mobile; `
                Manager           = $_.Manager; `
                Office            = $_.Branch; `
                postalCode        = $_.PostalCode; `
                POBox             = $_.PostOfficeBox; `
                scriptPath        = $_.scriptPath; `
                Street            = $_.StreetName; `
                Title             = $_.Title
        }
        if ($CurrentAttributes.city -ne $correctAttributes.city) {
            Set-ADUser -Identity $username -City $correctAttributes.City
            Write-Host "$username City Updated to $correctAttributes.City"
        }
        else {
            write-Host "$username city is correct"
        }

        if ($CurrentAttributes.Name -ne $correctAttributes.Name) {
            Set-ADUser -Identity $username -Name $correctAttributes.Name
            Write-Host "$username Name Updated to ($correctAttributes.Name)"
        }
        else {
            write-Host "$username Name is correct"
        }



        #$correctAttributes = @{}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write them dynamically using 'splatting' like this:

```
$csvFile = 'C:\Path'  # Enter a path to your import CSV file
$validUsernameFormat = '[^a-zA-Z_.]'                # identifies anything that's _not_ a-z or underscore or .
$Mailpassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -string “4a1fd5e9f7e26f” -AsPlainText -Force
$MailCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "38da1ca9daf082", $Mailpassword
$mailBody = $NewUserParams | out-string

# read the input csv and loop through
Import-Csv -Path $csvFile | ForEach-Object {
    $firstName = $_.FirstName.Trim()
    $surname = $_.Surname.Trim()
    #$validUsernameFormat = "[^a-zA-Z_.]"                                        # identifies anything that's _not_ a-z or underscore or .
    $vaildusername = "($firstName'.'$surname)" -replace $validUsernameFormat, ''       #removes anything that isn'tin $validUsernameFormat
    $truncateifgreaterthanXchar = '(?<=^.{20}).*'
    $username = $vaildusername -replace $truncateifgreaterthanXchar
    $DefaultPassword = 'Pa$$w0rd'
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $DefaultPassword -AsPlainText -Force

    # test if a user with that name already exists
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        $CurrentAttributes = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Properties *
        # You don't need this line because you are already declaring the variable in the next one
        # [psobject]$CorrectAttributes
        $CorrectAttributes = @{
            SamAccountName    = $username
            Name              = "$firstname $surname"
            DisplayName       = "$firstname $surname"
            UserPrincipalName = "$username@domain.com"
            GivenName         = $firstname
            Surname           = $surname
            Path              = "CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" #change to switch based of Users Branch
            City              = $_.City
            Country           = $_.Country #NOTE: This Feild must be the 2 digit Country Code, NOT the String Name of athe Country.
            department        = $_.OrgDepartmentName
            Employeeid        = $_.EmployeeId
            mobile            = $_.Mobile
            Manager           = $_.Manager
            Office            = $_.Branch
            postalCode        = $_.PostalCode
            POBox             = $_.PostOfficeBox
            scriptPath        = $_.scriptPath
            Street            = $_.StreetName
            Title             = $_.Title
        }
        foreach($attribute in $CorrectAttributes.Keys) {
            if($currentAttributes.$attribute -ne $correctAttributes.$attribute) {
                $params = @{Identity = $username; $attribute = $correctAttributes.$attribute}
                Set-ADUser @params
                Write-Host "$username '$attribute' updated to $correctAttributes.$attribute"
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "$username '$attribute' is correct"
            }
        }
    }
}
```